# Entity Framework Migrations em sistema já instalado, como executar?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, migrations

Uma aplicação C# WinForms, com o Entity Framework que acessa dados no SQL Server em fase de desenvolvimento usamos Migrations para deixar o banco de dados de acordo com o nosso modelo, mas e depois com o sistema já em produção? 
Geralmente nas estações de trabalho e nos servidores não temos o Visual Studio para executar o "database update", diante disto, e também diante da minha ignorância sobre o assunto pergunto como executar o Migrations no ambiente de produção?
Podemos usar o código criado pelo Migrations e adiconar uma funcionalidade a aplicação, e esta manterá o banco de dados de acordo com o modelo criado para a aplicação?
O que estou fazendo é usar o script do SQL gerado pelo Migrations para atualizar o banco de dados, depois de um backup de segurança para evitar perda de dados, mas seria esse o procedimento mais adequado?

Answer (score 0):

Se vc usa o migration:

Entao os seus primeiros passos sao:

```
Add-Migration primeiroExec
update-database
```

quando voce gera ou altera algum model entao vc vai refazer o mesmo processo:

```
Add-Migration minhaPrimeiraAlteracao
update-database
```

o `add-migration` vai gerar um arquivo na pasta migrations que vai conter o que vai ser alterado no banco de dados, e o `update-database` vai executar esse arquivo.

Caso fez alguma coisa errada so precisa retorna para o migration anterior:

```
Update-Database primeiroExec
```

Gerou o migration antes do tempo vc pode apagar e depois recriar:

```
Remove-Migration
```

Comment: Agradeço as informações @HudsonPH... Exatamente isto o que faço no ambiente de desenvolvimento, porém no ambiente de produção tem como fazer isso sem o visual studio  como mencionei na pergunta?

Comment: @AriVenuth Nao pq vc precisa do projeto para gerar o migration no seu caso de code first, o melhor e o que eu recomendo 'e nao usar migration, e ter o seu codigo livre do ef, caso vc muda por exemplo para dapper vc nao vai ter problemas.

Comment: Agradeço a dica para deixar meu código livre do EF, mas a esta altura do projeto isso é totalmente inviável. Então o mais indicado no meu caso, code first, é criar a migração inicial gerando o script SQL. Caso seja necessário uma mudança, criar a migração de adaptação gerando o devido script e rodar este no SQL de produção.